# How to embed WordPress site into a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, embed, headless-cms

How can I load my WordPress into a React (Next.js) component. Not page but component, because I would use the menu of the page.

I found many solution for the opposite way, React -> WordPress, but here I need **Wordpress -> React**.

Do I need here a headless WordPress with React?

As I understand headless CMS will use WordPress data / BE, but a custom FE can be created for data fetched data.

BUT! I would not write my own FrontEnd, I would use the WordPress one.

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-wordpress

Comment: The thing I do not understand why `WPGraphQL` is needed. WordPress site is a static site, right? I would not render any dinamic content. But also I would not load the "whole screen" on the page with WordPress, only the part under the menu. What do you think?